# Regex to capture different elements in unknown order of appearance in Python

Tags: python, regex, string, string-matching, regex-lookarounds

I am building a regex to extract the header values from a forwarded email in Python. I am only interested in the first appearance of these kinds of headers in an email and I only want to capture the text parts appearing after the colons.

```
From: ...  
Sent: ...   
To: ...   
Subject: ...
```

The following regex works fine using `re.search` for most variations of the above format:

```
(?:From\s*:\s*)(.*)(?:\n*)(?:Sent\s*:\s*)(.*)(?:\n*)(?:To\s*:\s*)(.*)(?:\n*)(?:Subject\s*:\s*)
```

but sometimes, the different header parts are ordered differently and have missing elements, such as below:

```
Sent: ...    
From: ...  
Subject: ...
```

I thought I could use a positive lookahead to match the header format in any order but I could not get this to work. Does anyone have any idea how this can be done efficiently? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.parser.html

Comment: I don't think I can use this library as my data set is multilingual.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility would be to never consume any characters, and use lookahead to capture everything you need in optional groups:

```
(?=(?:.*^From\s*:\s*)(.*?$)|)(?=(?:.*^Sent\s*:\s*)(.*?$)|)(?=(?:.*^To\s*:\s*)(.*?$)|)(?=(?:.*^Subject\s*:\s*)(.*?$)|)
```

https://regex101.com/r/pOThDP/2

Spaced out, that's just 4 repititions of a similar pattern that looks like:

```
(?=(?:.*^From\s*:\s*)(.*?$)|)
(?=(?:.*^Sent\s*:\s*)(.*?$)|)
(?=(?:.*^To\s*:\s*)(.*?$)|)
(?=(?:.*^Subject\s*:\s*)(.*?$)|)
```

Also, you might consider named capture groups, for clarity:

```
(?=(?:.*^From\s*:\s*)(?P<From>.*?$)|)(?=(?:.*^Sent\s*:\s*)(?P<Sent>.*?$)|)(?=(?:.*^To\s*:\s*)(?P<To>.*?$)|)(?=(?:.*^Subject\s*:\s*)(?P<Subject>.*?$)|)
```

https://regex101.com/r/pOThDP/3

Edit: Example in python code:

```
text = '''To: totext
Sent: sent text
this text has no no "from" label
Subject: subject text'''
pattern = re.compile(r'(?=(?:.*^From\s*:\s*)(.*?$)|)(?=(?:.*^Sent\s*:\s*)(.*?$)|)(?=(?:.*^To\s*:\s*)(.*?$)|)(?=(?:.*^Subject\s*:\s*)(.*?$)|)', flags=re.S | re.M)
match = re.search(pattern, text)
print(match.groups())
```

Output is:

```
(None, 'sent text', 'totext', 'subject text')
```

Comment: This looks great! When I try it out in regex101 it works (only issue is that it doesn't just capture the first occurrence). For some reason however, my python code finds a match in each email with this regex that captures only None for each of the values. I'm not sure why though.

Comment: Update: I forgot to set the m and s flags. It works perfectly now! Do you have any idea how this can be adapted to only return the first match for each of the different parts?

Comment: Make all the quantifiers before the label text lazy instead of greedy, eg `(?=(?:.*?^From` https://regex101.com/r/pOThDP/4

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant it differently.. Let's say the first header block contains only From, Sent, To, and the second block contains From, Sent, To, Subject, then I don't want the result to include the Subject line of the second forwarded block, but now that one is captured because the first block didn't contain that one.

Comment: Can you give a fuller example of the input and desired output? You might require there not be two line breaks in a row, maybe

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern: `\G(From:|Subject:|Sent:|To:)(.+)\n`

Requirement, that it should capture only first block, is fulfilled by `\G` anchor, which makes sure next match (Sent/To/From/Subject) is met right after the previous one, so header of another mail isn't matched, because it will be separated by content of an e-mail.

Alternation makes sure, that it will match the header independently of the order of Sent/To/From/Subject.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bm0XIq/1)